# Metaprogramming instance methods - something wrong with the syntax?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, metaprogramming

```
NAMES = ['orange', 'pear']

  Fruit.class_eval do
    NAMES.each do |n|
        define_method "is_#{n}?" do
          self.name == Fruit.find_by_name(n)
        end
    end
  end
```

For a fruit object, I want to be able to explicitly ask whether it's an orange or not, for example, by the fruit object's name attribute.  When I call Fruit.find_by_name('orange').is_orange? I get false.  What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I suspect you should be using [`instance_eval`](http://ilikestuffblog.com/2009/01/09/fun-with-rubys-instance_eval-and-class_eval/)

Comment: You can easily verify that your method is being invoked. As such, it's not the metaprogramming that is at fault, but your logic within the method. Check your ActiveRecord(?) thinking

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
self.name == Fruit.find_by_name(n)
```

seems wrong to me. Shouldnt you check

```
self.name == n
```

??

And you should indeed use instance_eval.

Also, I think it would be more ruby-like to name your method orange? instead of is_orange?.

Comment: ok, instance_eval makes sense for the question asked, but wouldn't it make even more sense to simply define those methods inside the class?